# How to insert a row as the second-last row?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

There are a lot of similar questions but every single one I could find is using jQuery which I want to mitigate. The content of the inserted row will be created dynamically. My broken approach:

```js
function addRow() {
  let newRow = '<tr><td>Boo</td><td>✔</td><td></td><td>✔</td></tr>';
  document.getElementById('new').insertBefore(newRow);
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}

th {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

#new {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#new:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: grey;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>multiple</th>
      <th>required</th>
      <th>special</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>✔</td>
      <td>✔</td>
      <td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>✔</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="new" colspan="6" onClick="addRow">ADD NEW SETTING</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please feel free to optimize the code however you want if you think it should be done differently.

Comment: you are using [insertbefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) wrong, see the document.

Comment: Building a table (or any element) using HTML strings is not recommended. See [HTMLTable interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).

Comment: @Teemu Could you create an answer with a better solution or point me to another question/resource so I can create one myself? Maybe you could also edit your answer, @appleapple?

Comment: @MiXT4PE Unfortunately I've not time to answer right now, please see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwcsjaLo/), it shows the basics how to use `table.insertRow` and `row.insertCell` methods.

Comment: @Teemu I cooked up an answer to represent your comment for future viewers of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Teemu suggested it is **better practice** to use the [HTMLTable Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) instead of using using strings of HTML:

```js
function addRow() {
  const tbody = document.getElementById('dictionary');
  const row = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length - 1);
  ['Boo', '', '✔', '✔'].forEach(
    cell => row.insertCell().textContent = cell
  );
}
```

```css
body {padding: 50px; font-family: sans-serif;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td {padding: 15px;}
th {text-transform: capitalize;}
#new {text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}
#new:hover {cursor: pointer; background-color: grey; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="dictionary">
    <tr>
      <th>title</th><th>multiple</th><th>required</th><th>special</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td><td>✔</td><td>✔</td><td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td><td>✔</td><td></td><td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="new" colspan="6" onClick="addRow()">ADD NEW SETTING</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
function addRow() {
  let newRow = '<tr><td>Boo</td><td>✔</td><td></td><td>✔</td></tr>';
  document.getElementById('new').parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', newRow)
}
```

```css
body {padding: 50px; font-family: sans-serif;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td {padding: 15px;}
th {text-transform: capitalize;}
#new {text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}
#new:hover {cursor: pointer; background-color: grey; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>title</th><th>multiple</th><th>required</th><th>special</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td><td>✔</td><td>✔</td><td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td><td>✔</td><td></td><td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="new" colspan="6" onClick="addRow()">ADD NEW SETTING</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```